Using sort for reformatting the variable length records
I have a input with comma delimited records
Each field will be of different variables length
Example
5467,2,567.82
243,10,856
Now I want output to be written as below first field length in the output should be 10 second field length should be 15 and third field length should be 15 with leading zeroes
Order 0000005467 count 000000000000002 amount 000000000567.82
Order 0000000243 count 000000000000010 amount 000000000000856
i have tried below jcl but the amount field is not populated to right justified its populating to left justified as 567820000000.00

//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SYNCSORT

//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*

//SORTIN  DD DSN=input,DISP=SHR

//SORTOUT DD DSN=output1,

//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),

//             UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(5,5),RLSE)

//SYSIN   DD *

  OPTION COPY

  INREC PARSE=(%00=(ENDBEFR=C',',FIXLEN=10),

               %01=(ENDBEFR=C',',FIXLEN=15),

               %02=(FIXLEN=15)),

   BUILD=(%00,%01,%02)

   OUTREC BUILD=(1,10,UFF,M11,LENGTH=10,

                 11,15,UFF,M11,LENGTH=15,

                 26,10,ZD,EDIT=(TTTTTTTT.TT))

/*

//STEP2   EXEC PGM=SYNCSORT

//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*

//SORTIN  DD DSN=output1,DISP=SHR

//SORTOUT DD DSN=outputfinal,

//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),


//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*

//SORTIN  DD DSN=TSO.TESTFIS.CDS.CNTRL.RPTS.TT61824,DISP=SH

//SORTOUT DD DSN=TSO.TESTFIS.CDS.CNTRL.RPTS.TT61824.FINALB,

//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),

//             UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(5,5),RLSE)

//SYSIN   DD *

  OPTION COPY

  INREC PARSE=(%00=(FIXLEN=10),

               %01=(FIXLEN=15),

               %02=(FIXLEN=15)),

    BUILD=(C'ORDER # ',

           %00,

           C'  COUNT = ',

           %01,

           C' AMOUNT = ',

           %02)

/*



output should be
Order 0000005467 count 000000000000002 amount 000000000567.82
Order 0000000243 count 000000000000010 amount 000000000000856

Order 0000005467 count 000000000000002 amount 000000000567.82                                           Order 0000000243 count 000000000000010 amount 000000000000856

Your input has both numeric digits with decimal dot as well as pure integers. so you need to handle them a bit differently
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT                                              
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                
//SORTIN   DD *                                                       
5467,2,567.82                                                         
243,10,856       
1,2,59.8                                                     
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                                
//SYSIN    DD *                                                       
  OPTION COPY    
  ALTSEQ CODE=(40F0)                                                        
* parse the comma separated fields                                    
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,                                            
         PARSE=(%01=(ENDBEFR=C',',FIXLEN=10),                         
                %02=(ENDBEFR=C',',FIXLEN=15),                         
                %03=(ENDBEFR=C',',FIXLEN=15)),                        
         BUILD=(%01,UFF,M11,LENGTH=10,                                
                %02,UFF,M11,LENGTH=15,                                
                %03)),                                                
                                                                      
* Check if the amount has decimal dot and parse it as number & decimal
                                                                      
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(26,15,SS,EQ,C'.'),                              
         PARSE=(%04=(ABSPOS=26,ENDBEFR=C'.',FIXLEN=12),               
                %05=(FIXLEN=02)),                                     
       OVERLAY=(26:%04,UFF,M11,LENGTH=12,                             
                   C'.',                                              
                   %05,TRAN=ALTSEQ)),                                
                                                                      
* There is no decimal dot, so just pad leading zeroes                 
                                                                      
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,                                            
       OVERLAY=(26:26,15,UFF,M11,LENGTH=15))                          
                                                                      
* Write the final output                                              
                                                                      
  OUTREC BUILD=(C'ORDER ',01,10,                                      
                C' COUNT ',11,15,                                     
                C' AMOUNT ',26,15)                                    
                                                                      
/*                                                                    

The Output from above is
ORDER 0000005467 COUNT 000000000000002 AMOUNT 000000000567.82
ORDER 0000000243 COUNT 000000000000010 AMOUNT 000000000000856
ORDER 0000000001 COUNT 000000000000002 AMOUNT 000000000059.80


Hi, thanks for the help , can you please help if the input has one digit after decimal like 59.8 then  output should be 0000059.80

It would have been nice if you provided the feedback after you received the solution, but you came back for a solution when requirement changed. I will edit the solution to handle it. Basically it needs 2 changes.

Add this ALTSEQ CODE=(40F0) as new line AFTER statement OPTION COPY
Change the statement %05,UFF,EDIT=(TT))),  TO  %05,TRAN=ALTSEQ)),


Hi Kolusu, apologies for  not giving feedback , thankyou for the solution i will try the next one and let you know

Hi Thankyou so much, it worked
